# Send BinarySecurityToken with MTOM

Tags: java, soap, spring-ws, ws-security, mtom

I'm trying to send a SOAP message using the Spring-WS framework which has to be signed with a certificate. The service uses MTOM encoding and requires all attachments to be send this way, including the signing certificate (BinarySecurityToken).

I've set MTOM to true on the Marshaller `jaxb2Marshaller.setMtomEnabled(true);` and tried using the `SaajSoapMessageFactory` and `AxiomSoapMessageFactory` but the BinarySecurityToken is still just `Base64` encoded and inlined.

This is what is generated:

```
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-31f7042b-edbf-480d-a191-6f4c06fce9b0">Base64#Token</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

But the service expects something like this:

```
<o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-3e274ba8-bba3-4092-880d-adf41081fcaf-1" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/1/637798371206427416" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
</o:BinarySecurityToken>
```

Is this possible with Spring-WS?